# Customising the syntax colour in Sublime Text 3

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

I'm in the process of creating my own syntax colour theme for Sublime Text 3. I've done quite a lot but I want to copy most of the JavaScript colour syntax from the default 'Cobalt' theme that comes with ST3 (and possibly mix-and-match from other themes). I can't seem to find the Cobalt theme anywhere on my Mac?

Any ideas on where this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of navigating through `/Applications`, the easiest way of accessing built-in packages in Sublime Text 3 is to use @skuroda's excellent [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin, available through Package Control. Once installed, restart Sublime and hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Palette. Type ***`prv`*** to bring up the `PackageResourceViewer` options, and select `Open Resource`. Scroll down to `Color Scheme - Default`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then scroll down to select `Cobalt.tmTheme` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can now hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get rid of the menu, and start looking through the theme file for the bits you want to copy.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime Text installation directory, if I'm not mistaken, that's `/Applications/` on OS X, there's a `Packages` directory, which contains a package file `Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package` which contains all the default color schemes.

`.sublime-package` is a simple zip file with modified extension, so you may simply copy it somewhere in your home directory, extract it and browse through the Cobalt.tmTheme file.

P.S. If you have trouble opening it with OS X archive manager, you may simply rename it:

```
mv name.sublime-package name.zip
```

But as far as I remember, it could be done simply like (correct me here if I'm wrong)

```
unzip name.sublime-package -d somedir
```